Source-NAT not working in a double router setup
A Source-NAT configuration described below is not working as expected through a port forwarding and I don't understand why.
I have a device (ip: 172.31.1.120) whose gateway points toward a router with ip of 172.31.1.254. Since I need to access the device remotely through 5G, I have another router now (172.31.1.140) connected to the same swich which is connected to the original router and I want to use it to access the device's port 102 from my laptop that is in the 5G-net and has ip of 172.16.1.24
The problem is that I cannot change any configuration on the original router, or define static routes, or chage the device gateway and can only configure my own router shown with blue color in the below diagram. So the gateway of the device is fixed toward the original router.
Because of this I have configured a source-NAT with a source ip of 172.16.1.32  (my remote laptop) and translated ip of 172.31.1.140 (my new router that is connected directly to the same switch that the original router is connected). This is in addition port forwarding from 172.16.1.32:102 to 172.31.1.120.
However, when I scan the 102 port from my remote laptop, it appears as filtered.
When I connect my laptops lan socket directly to the switchand scan it with nmap the port 502 appears open.
In general I am sure that my configuration of port-forwarding is correct because I have done this before with a couple of other devices with the same 5G-router model.
However, when I scan this port with nmap (nmap 172.16.1.32 -p 102), it shows the port being filtered.
Why is the Source-NAT does not completely represent the same scenario where my laptop is connected directly to the switch?

